# Constant DB_HOST already defined

Tags: php

This is My Connection File how to fix my error

```
Constant DB_HOST already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS_TEMPLATE\include\db.php on line 10

Notice: Constant DB_USER already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS_TEMPLATE\include\db.php on line 10

Notice: Constant DB_PASS already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS_TEMPLATE\include\db.php on line 10

Notice: Constant DB_NAME already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS_TEMPLATE\include\db.php on line 10
```

```
<?php 

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";

foreach($db as $key  =>  $value)
{
define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}
$conn=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

if($conn){
    echo "connected";
} 
else{
    echo "not";
}

?>
```

Comment: Run it though array_unique  before looping for it.  Also define is really slow and the fact that you are using enough of them to need a loop is concerning.  Your problem resides elsewhere in your code.  Probably a include instead of include_once.

Comment: @AlexBarker is right if you are including this connection files to each pages than you should include it once.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `defined` function that you can call to check if it's already defined before defining it in your loop.

```
foreach($db as $key  =>  $value)
{
    if(!defined(strtoupper($key))){ define(strtoupper($key), $value); }
}
```

You can also use either an `include_once` or `require_once` with your `db.php` file so you don't accidentally include it twice and run into this problem in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Please check key is already defined or not using `defined`

chnage

```
define(strtoupper($key), $value);
```

to

```
 defined(strtoupper($key)) ||  define(strtoupper($key), $value);
```